# Most common synonym of liturgy?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I'm not a native speaker. So when you go to the church, what it's the most common word to describe the liturgy?

Complete the phrase:

I'm going to the _______ (the event of prayer that takes place in a church)

Comment: I think you may be confused over the meaning of "liturgy". It refers to the form in which worship takes place, not to the actual name of a service - such as, in a Catholic Church, "Mass", which in an Anglican church would be called "Holy Communion". Many other names are used such as "Evensong" etc.

Comment: Google `synonym liturgy`.

Comment: *prayer meeting*

Comment: There is also the word *service*.  **I'm going to the service.**  It could be a regularly scheduled service, or something less regular like a funeral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often you would use the name of the particular service.  E.g. As an ex-Anglican I could refer to going ______:

- Morning Prayer
- Communion
- Evensong
- Compline

In my sojourn in Mormon country I heard references to going to "Sacrament" "Priesthood meeting" "Bible Study" "Mutual Improvement Association"  It wasn't clear as a gentile, which of these were religious forms of worship, and which were efforts at building a local community.

So for your question I would answer it either:

"I'm going to church"  -- Implying a generic religious observance. Used when talking to someone who is not religious, or not of your faith, or unaccustomed to your faith.

"I'm going to {name of service} -- speaking to someone who is at least somewhat familiar with your pattern of religious observances.

This help?

Liturgy is more abstract.

liturgy (ˈlɪtədʒɪ)
n, pl -gies
1. (Ecclesiastical Terms) the forms of public services officially prescribed by a Church
2. (Ecclesiastical Terms) (often capital) chiefly Eastern Churches Also called: Divine Liturgy the Eucharistic celebration
3. (Ecclesiastical Terms) a particular order or form of public service laid down by a Church
[C16: via Medieval Latin, from Greek leitourgia, from leitourgos minister, from leit- people + ergon work]
Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014 © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014
lit•ur•gy (ˈlɪt ər dʒi)

n., pl. -gies.
1. a form of public worship; ritual.
2. a collection of formularies for public worship.
3. a particular arrangement of services.
4. a particular form or type of the Eucharistic service.
5. the service of the Eucharist, esp. this service (Divine Liturgy) in the Eastern Church.

Comment: I'm old enough to remember when "Morning Prayer" was called "Matins", in my then English parish where the vicar had a somewhat "High-Church" approach. "Holy Communion, Matins and Evensong" were his Sunday ritual.

Answer (score -1):

The event that takes place is "Worship". The style of the way worship is presented is "Liturgy".

Comment: I agree, but people don't say "I'm going to the worship", do they. "Going to the service" is idiomatic. Or the word "service" could be replaced by the name of the service.